# Setting up Kubernetes Highly Available clusters with kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes

I am following [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/) to set up a new Kubernetes cluster. As part of this process, I have to set up an etcd cluster. I am following [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/setup-ha-etcd-with-kubeadm/) for that.

After installing kubelet on my etcd cluster, it does not start. I see the following in the logs:

> Jun 20 17:14:08 etcd1 kubelet: F0620 17:14:08.505594   13809
>   server.go:198] failed to load Kubelet config file
>   /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file
>   "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml", error: open
>   /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml: no such file or directory

I am stuck due to this error. I need kubelet running to proceed as per documentation.